# Having problem with setup project in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-project

i have create a c# form application for parsing Html using Winista.html parser.
Now i have created a setup project for this and when i install the setup and run it generates error

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Winista.HtmlParser,
Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The 
system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Winista.HtmlParser, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
at Investigator.Form1.googleNewsSearcher()
```

Why is this happening ? Why is it not finding the dll , i pasted the winistal.HTMLParser in the bin folder ,and add reference to it .Is there any thing missing please help this is very urgent , i have to submit this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu have to add a reference, when you create a setup project it doesn't look in the bin folder for assemblies it checks references. You should be able to add the assembly to the setup project. I would suggest that you add it as a reference though.

You might also need to re-add the primary project to the setup project once you do this, but I think a rebuild should solve it once you added the reference to the assembly.

Update 
Try right clicking on the reference and select copy always. This will insure that the assembly is always coppied to the bin folder.

Comment: but i added reference in the C# code not in setup project,do i have to add reference in setup project?

Comment: No, if you added a reference after you created the setup project, then try removing the primary project from the setup project, and re-adding it. VS is sometimes funny like this.

Comment: i added the reference before creating the setup project

Comment: Can you see the dll in the root folder were you installed the project?

Comment: there is debug and release folder and i dont find it in any , what i did now is i added assembly in the setup project and is working but when i move the setup file to the desktop it is not running when i leave it in the folder and go to folder and run its running.

Comment: When reference is added correctly, you were able to see "Detected Dependencies" folder in setup project containing referenced assembly. If this folder is missing, you must recreate all projects in the solution (or entire solution), add reference to library and after that, create setup project.

Comment: Yes in the detected dependencies folder i see winistal.htmlparser

Comment: Right-click winistal.htmlparser assembly in "detected dependencies" folder and select properties. Is "Vital" property set to true?

Comment: Your's setup project may be corrupted. Try to create a new one.

Comment: actually i created a new and when i build it i am getting this warning.
Warning 1 Unable to find dependency 'ICSHARPCODE.SHARPZIPLIB' (Signature='1B03E6ACF1164F73' Version='0.83.1.0') of assembly 'Winista.HtmlParser.dll' E:\Setup1\Setup1\Setup1.vdproj Setup1

Comment: @ConfusedCoder after downloading there files I see that there is a ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll, you must also add a reference to this dll if you have not already.

Comment: how to add reference to ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll?

Comment: Right click on your project, not your setup project. Select add reference and browse for the dll, click add select dll when done. Simple.

Comment: problem solved i think by adding the winistal.htmlparser as assembly in the project solution
Thank you all for you time and help